# Good ways to define functions inside function in R

Tags: r, function

In R, when want to use one/multiple functions inside another function, maybe there are two ways. An example function can be:

**Method 1:**

```
make.power <- function(n) {
 pow <- function(x) {
 x^n
 }
 pow
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
make.power <- function(n) {
     pow(n)
    }

pow <- function(x) {
     x^n
     }
```

In my opinion (but I am not sure), the second method is a better way if you have lots of child functions for the parent one.

**My questions are:**
1) Are there any functional differences between the two ways? E.g., how the function will pass variables, or the relationship between the children and parent functions, etc..

2) which one might be a preferred one (maybe more computational efficient or structurally clear) for R?

Comment: You should read through [this chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping) for the details of how functions behave when they're defined within other functions. Besides that, question 1 is a bit broad (there are differences- in what situation?), and question 2 is partly opinion-based.

Comment: I agree with @DavidRobinson about the breadth of this question. I think the main difference in your methods is the obvious one: in Method 1 `pow` is only internal to `make.power`, whereas in Method 2 is is external and thus available to other functions. Which is preferable depends on context: do you have a use for `pow` outside of `make.power`?  Is this in a package, where you choice might also involve whether or not to export `pow`?

Comment: Don't really get why this is too broad... the concept itself is broad but the example he gives has a clear example and is very demonstrative of R's lazy evaluation.

Comment: When I was writing functions inside function, I got confused about the two different ways to structure them, so I gave a specific example to understand it. Senor O's answer help make the difference clear. I also found DavidRobinson and Gregor gave very helpful hint to help understand it deeper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are asking about the specific example you gave, this question does not seem too broad to me.

The main difference here is the evaluation of `n`. For **example 1**, the function that gets returned will essentially have a hard-coded `n` value.

```
> n = 100
> f1 = make.power(2)
> f1(2)
[1] 4
> n = 1
> f1(2)
[1] 4
```

**Example 2** will not, instead it will rely on the global definition of `n`.

```
> n = 1
> make.power2(2)
[1] 2
> n = 100
> make.power2(2)
[1] 1.267651e+30
```

As functions get more complex, so will the scoping issues. The link David Robinson provides in the comments is a great resource.