# Define lapply function

Tags: r, lapply

I have a tab called df containing the results of several classifiers: Accuracy, Npv, Ppv etc.

I would like to add a new column to the data frame called "Points" containing this weighted calculation:

```
Points = Accuracy* 0,20 + Specificity *0,10 + Sensitivity *0.35 + Neg Pre Value*0.10 + Pos Pred value*0.25)
```

I'm trying to use lapply in this way:

```
df$Points <- apply(df[,3:7],1,make.calc)
```

The function will make its calculation starting from the 3rd column up to the 7th and store the results in a new column called Points.

I have also defined my function make.calc in this way:

```
make.calc <- function(x) {
t <- function(x) { 
df$Accuracy * 0.2 + df$Specificity * 0.1 + df$Sensitivity * 0.35 + df$Neg_Pred_Value * 0.1 + df$Pos_Pred_Value * 0.25 }
 t }
```

But what I'm getting is a new column called Points containing a string with the model defined above...not the calculation I need!

Can anyone help me in understanding what's wrong with my code please??

Here's the dput of my df:

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(Model = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Decision Tree", 
"Naive Bayes", "Neural Networks", "Random Forest", "SVM Linear", 
"SVM Radial"), class = "factor"), `Data source` = c("Without_DownSampling", 
"Without_DownSampling", "Without_DownSampling", "Without_DownSampling", 
"Without_DownSampling", "Without_DownSampling"), Specificity = c("0.984", 
"0.490", "0.980", "0.998", "0.982", "0.980"), `Pos Pred Value` = c("0.937", 
"0.321", "0.917", "0.991", "0.924", "0.917"), Accuracy = c("0.980", 
"0.588", "0.969", "0.996", "0.966", "0.967"), Sensitivity = c("0.963", 
"0.991", "0.926", "0.991", "0.898", "0.917"), `Neg Pred Value` = c("0.991", 
"0.995", "0.982", "0.998", "0.975", "0.980")), .Names = c("Model", 
"Data source", "Specificity", "Pos Pred Value", "Accuracy", "Sensitivity", 
"Neg Pred Value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `transform(df, Points = Accuracy * 0.20 + 
                       Specificity * 0.1 + 
                       Sensitivity * 0.35 + 
                       Neg_Pred_Value * 0.1 + 
                       Pos_Pred_Value * 0.25)`

Comment: that's not how you define a function in R. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255367/good-ways-to-define-functions-inside-function-in-r

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers!!! The fransform () function is not working since an error pops out : ```Error in Accuracy * 0.2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator```

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) along with expected output so that it is easier for others to help you.

Comment: Example added!!!

Comment: `transform(df, Points = Accuracy * 0.20 + Specificity * 0.1 + Sensitivity * 0.35 + Neg_Pred_Value * 0.1 + Pos_Pred_Value * 0.25)` this seems to work on your example data

Comment: It keeps on saying ```Error in Accuracy * 0.2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator```. I don't know what's wrong! My summary says also that every indices(Accuracy, Specificity etc) is like this: Length:6 Class :character Mode  :character

Comment: Are you certain that your *actual* `df` is a frame structured as you made in the reprex here in the question? If you define it with the sample values above but it is a `matrix`, then all will be `character`. If you read it from a file, it's possible that `Accuracy` is a factor because of some oddity found in the file. It would be very insightful (to us) to add the output of `dput(head(df))` (*your* version, not necessarily this one); console output masks a lot of problems, `dput` output is unambiguous in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answers! I have edited my question again

Comment: I'm commenting since this is a data.table solution, you can first convert the data.frame to data.table using as.data.table or setDT. Then you can
`df[, Points := Accuracy * 0.20 + Specificity * 0.1 + Sensitivity * 0.35 + "Neg Pred Value" * 0.1 + "Pos Pred Value" * 0.25]` (Please enclose the column names containing spaces with backticks (`) so that they can be evaluated as column names)

Comment: Hi @YonP, thanks for your answer..but it doesn't work. I have done what you said and the ```Error in Accuracy * 0.2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator``` keeps on popping out

Comment: That is because the columns Accuracy, Specificity, Sensitivity, Neg Pred Value, & Pos Pred Value are in character format. If you tried the data.table solution, try running this first before the creation of Points column. ``df[, `:=` (Accuracy = as.numeric(Accuracy), Specificity = as.numeric(Specificity), Sensitivity = as.numeric(Sensitivity), `Neg Pred Value` = as.numeric(`Neg Pred Value`), `Pos Pred Value` = as.numeric(`Pos Pred Value`))]``, again please enclose the column names containing spaces with backticks (`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you've provided, almost all of the variables are classifed as strings. Unfortunately, you can't perform any calculations on strings, so you should first convert them all to numeric variables.

```
df <- data.frame(purrr::map_at(df, 3:7, as.numeric), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This would be one approach, but I'm sure there are other better options. You would also need to fix your variable names so there are no spaces within them. Note that `Neg Pre Value` isn't a good name - suggest you adjust to `Neg_Pre_Value` or something similar.

Then you don't need a function to perform the task you wanted.

You could simply define the new variable like this:

```
df$Points <- df$Accuracy * 0.2 + df$Specificity * 0.1 + df$Sensitivity * 0.35 + df$Neg_Pred_Value * 0.1 + df$Pos_Pred_Value * 0.25
```